# How can I show a datetime timestamp formatted as 24 hour format in Google Data Studio?

Tags: datetime, timestamp, format, looker-studio

I have a field, timestamp, in Data Studio. The type is DateTime.
[image]

When I try to sort on timestamp, the order is not correct, and it seems to be because it is not using 24 hour format.
[image]  [image]

How can I show a datetime timestamp formatted as 24 hour format in Google Data Studio?

I have tried different uses of FORMAT_DATETIME, TODATE and PARSE_DATETIME, but can't get it to work correctly.

What I **have**, is the format "May 17, 2021, 2:37:55 PM".

What I **want** is the format "2021-05-17, 14:37:55"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It can be achieved using the [`FORMAT_DATETIME`](https://support.google.com/datastudio/answer/9730334) function below, where `timestamp` represents the field (`%F` formats the **Date** as `YYYY-MM-DD` while `%T` formats the **Time** as `HH:MM:SS`; for a full list of the supported symbols and their respective use case, have a look through the [Supported format elements for DATETIME](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/datetime_functions#supported_format_elements_for_datetime)):

```
FORMAT_DATETIME("%F, %T", timestamp)
```

[Editable Google Data Studio Report](https://datastudio.google.com/reporting/166e1791-fa0e-409a-89f7-f3337ebdf409) (Embedded [Google Sheets](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1OJH4AeHEtYgkMvMO-LDC-GNLxownuFKRDsyArUd8BuI/edit?usp=sharing) Data Source) and a GIF to elaborate:

[image]